# Add newly created columns to an existing PostGIS table from GeoPandas?

Tags: postgis, sql, geopandas

I am trying to add some newly created columns to an existing table in PostGIS table from GeoPandas.

Previously, I've pulled the data out of my database, run geocoding, and then created new columns by manipulating the results. I now want to update my table with these new columns, but running the `to_postgis` function with the `if_exists=append` option produces a `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column of relation does not exist.`

I assume this means that I need to do this via formatting an SQL statement and then executing it, but I was hoping there was some magic that would save me the trouble.

Comment: `if_exists=append` does not allow for the addition of new fields to a table, only new rows. You would need the field to exist within the table to have it work in the way you would want.

Comment: That's correct - however ADD COLUMN statements are easy enough to run using Psycopg2 or SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Joe Be's comment, it's necessary to either write a SQL statement to add the additional columns to the DB, or to do so manually before running the script.

Comment: maybe exporting as a geopackage and then calling ogr2ogr with the -addfields handle for the importing. Use tempfile for this temp geopackage to be cleaned swiftly.

Answer (score 0):

Use ogr2ogr with "-addfields" handle, supposing that your GeoDataFrame is "gdf":

```
import tempfile, subprocess, os
import geopandas as gpd

# replace with your database credentials/specs:
db_name = ''
db_host = ''
db_port = ''
db_user = ''
db_schema=''
db_password = ''

# replace with your table name:
table_name = 'MY_TABLE'

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
    temp_gpkg_path = os.path.join(temp_dir,'temp.gpkg')
    
    db_str = f'PG:"dbname={db_name} host={db_host} port={db_port} user={db_user} active_schema={db_schema} password={db_password}"'
    
    runstring = f'ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" {db_str} "{temp_gpkg_path}" -nln {table_name} -addfields -forceNullable' # according to the documentation the last handle is important
    # other suggested options: -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -append -progress
    
    subprocess.run(runstring,shell=True)
```

For complete reference on ogr2ogr, [check de documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html)